# Javascript ternary operator

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, java

I need to set a constant value as true or false for the particular scenario not sure correct working or not

```
const test = data.findIndex(d => d.Fname === '' && d.Lname === '') < 0 ? false : true;
```

if fname and Lname both are blank then i want to set test as false not sure what is happening here.

Comment: You don't need a ternary operator. Just this would be okay `const test = (data.findIndex(d => d.Fname === '' && d.Lname === '') < 0)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the '<' to '>=' which means there is at least one element in data which satisfies your condition of both Fname and Lname as blank.

```
const test = data.findIndex(d => d.Fname === '' && d.Lname === '') >= 0 ? false : true;
```